# Getting Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/tools/keytool/CertAndKeyGen

Tags: java, security, encryption, jboss, java-8

I am using Java `jre 1.8` on `SUSE linux` and i am getting exception on `sun/security/tools/keytool/CertAndKeyGen` class . I have build my code with JDK 1.8 with maven argument

```
<compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file<compilerArgument>
```

for sun/security/tools/keytool/ on java 8 . Build was successful . After deploying it on jboss , i am getting the error with  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` . This is the complete stack trace :

```
JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report

JBWEB000068: message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/tools/keytool/CertAndKeyGen

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/tools/keytool/CertAndKeyGen
    com.sample.test.security.certificate.OracleJDKCertificateHelper.resetCertificate(OracleJDKCertificateHelper.java:68)
    com.sample.test.service.singleton.CertificateService.resetCertificate(CertificateService.java:229)
    com.sample.test.service.singleton.CertificateService.resetCertificate(CertificateService.java:219)
    com.sample.test.service.singleton.LicenseService.postSaveOrUpdate(LicenseService.java:138)
    com.sample.test.service.singleton.LicenseService.postSaveOrUpdate(LicenseService.java:54)
    com.sample.test.service.singleton.SingletonServiceImpl.saveOrUpdate(SingletonServiceImpl.java:102)
    com.sample.test.web.controllers.singleton.BaseSingletonController$2.doInSyncMode(BaseSingletonController.java:110)
    com.sample.test.web.controllers.singleton.BaseSingletonController.doIfNotAsyncAction(BaseSingletonController.java:143)
    com.sample.test.web.controllers.singleton.BaseSingletonController.processSubmit(BaseSingletonController.java:103)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I have extracted `rt.jar` from SUSE `Jre1.8` . I can see that `rt.jar\sun\security\tools\keytool\CertAndKeyGen.class` is existing in it . Then why i am getting  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ?

Any help or suggestions ?

Comment: The keytool is not included with the JRE, if I remember correctly. Try running your server on a JDK instead.

Comment: Thanks . It is working fine .